# Rotate video using CGAffine Transform in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone

I am trying to rotate video using `CGAffineTransform`. For rotating video by 90 degrees, I have written below code.

```
var translateToCenter = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0,y: -(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width));
var rotateBy90Degrees = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi/2);
```

It worked fine. Now, I want to rotate video by 180, 270, 360 degrees, but couldn't figure it out.
Can any one help me out?

Answer (score 0):

rotation use radian, so you just need to convert degree to radian

```
let rad =  degree * .pi / 180
```